# How to have multiple graphs in one figure in ggplot

Tags: python-ggplot

I would like to have multiple graphs in one figure using ggplot. Much like a subplot in matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/181